# LAMP сервер (python) не работет

Tags: python, apache, веб-сервер, lamp

Установил LAMP(python) сервер. все по порядку сделал как сказано тут, [how to set up LAMP](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04)
. все работает, записывает данные в mysql и читает тоже.

но когда в основном файле index.py удаляю все и пишу простую команду, например

```
print('test msg')
```

и зхожу в localhost на браузере, то ничего не работает и выдает такую ошибку:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

я в этом новичек первый раз работаю с сервером, Помогите пожfлуйста что делать?

p.s. у меня стоит Ubuntu desktop 14, python 3.4

Comment: очевидно, «удалять всё» — нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, а решение какое? что мне оставить?

Comment: без содержимого файла ответить будет несколько сложно.

Comment: если вы перейдете по ссылке, которую я указал в теме, то там в самом низу есть код, который записывает в mysql данные а потом читает их. у меня точно такойже код.

Comment: как минимум стоило оставить все строки выше `import pymysql`.

Comment: но я же не работяю с mysql... он нужен когда я буду подключатся к mysql... или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: все строки **выше** указанной. смотрите в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте оставить в файле хотя бы эти строки:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Turn on debug mode.
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

# ваша строка:
print('test msg')
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, обязательно почитаю про cgitb

Comment: я думаю, без упоминаний `cgitb` тоже будет работать. но почитать, наверно, сто́ит.